# vips is failing on large image

Tags: jpeg, tiff

My tiff pyramid image conversion failed with the following error:

> JPEGPreEncode: Strip/tile too large for JPEG

I had been using the following command:

```
vips tiffsave 1000x512.v newHUGEfile.tiff --compression jpeg --vips-progress --vips-cache-trace --bigtiff
```

Is there a way to avoid this symptom ?

Answer (score 4):

How large is your test image? The jpeg encoder can't go over 65536 pixels in any axis. If your image is wider than that, you can't write it as a jpeg-compressed strip image.

Try adding `--tile`. This writes a tiled tiff image, where each tile is a separate 256x256 pixel region. Now the jpeg compressor will never see huge chunks at once and it ought to work.